# How to allow internet only to specific users while others need to access the local network?

Tags: windows, local-area-network, windows-server-2019, intranet

There are almost 50 users in my office. I want to provide internet access only up to some specific systems (5-6 nos). Remaining systems need to be disconnected from the internet. But it must be interconnected by LAN and must have an internal communication application (through any intranet communication app). Server 2019 is there, but it is now using as a file server. No AD/DC is set up on the server. How can I make this possible?

Comment: Hi Raj, welcome to Server Fault! There are multiple ways to do this, one example is to not set the default gateway on the hosts that shouldn't have internet. What kind of router to you use?

Comment: Hi Jornane, for now I have set it as you said. Putting up the default gateway to an IP not existing on the LAN. I'm using a basic router (TP Link C5)

Answer (score 0):

Require authentication to access a VLAN with Internet. Such as by implementing 802.1x.